# Unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved, dagger android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

My current project is in Java and I am trying to convert it to kotlin class by class. 
I try to inject a dependency in my kotlin fragment with the following code

```
    @Inject
lateinit var appCMSPresenter: AppCMSPresenter
```

in onViewCreated

```
(activity?.applicationContext as AppCMSApplication).appCMSPresenterComponent.inject(this)
```

It gives me the following error

```
ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class LoginFragment1 extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {

 public interface AppCMSPresenterComponent {
 warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[stagGeneratedPackageName, kapt.kotlin.generated, stagAssumeHungarianNotation, stagDebug]'
```

> Task :AppCMS:kaptMobileNonflavourDebugKotlin FAILED
>          ^

This is my dagger component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppCMSPresenterModule.class})
public interface AppCMSPresenterComponent {
AppCMSPresenter appCMSPresenter();

void inject(LoginFragment fragment);

void inject(LoginFragment1 fragment);

}
```

Module

```
@Module(includes = {AppCMSSearchModule.class})
public class AppCMSPresenterModule {
@Provides
@Singleton
public ReferenceQueue<Object> providesReferenceQueue() {
    return new ReferenceQueue<>();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public AppCMSPresenter providesAppCMSPresenter(Gson gson,
                                               AppCMSArticleCall appCMSArticleCall,
                                               AppCMSPhotoGalleryCall appCMSPhotoGalleryCall,
                                               AppCMSScheduleCall appCMSScheduleCall) {
    return new AppCMSPresenter(gson,
            appCMSArticleCall,
            appCMSPhotoGalleryCall, appCMSScheduleCall)
}
```

I am adding dependency in LoginFragment1

What could be the issue?

Comment: Since you're injecting objects from `AppCMSPresenterComponent`,  `AppCMSPresenter` should be exposed in `AppCMSPresenterModule`. Is it?

Comment: @OmarAflak AppCMSPresenter is exposed in AppCMSPresenterModule code updated